# Why express.static() not load my .js and .css files from correct path?

Tags: javascript, express, single-page-application

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
const path = require('path');

let lobbies = new Array();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public', 'index.html')); 
});
```

After refreshing page on http://localhost:8081/CreateGame/js/game I get my index.html file but all my .js and .css files trying to get them on http://localhost:8081/CreateGame/js/game.js when it should be http://localhost:8081/js/game
I have no idea how I should set this up, thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was witch src path in index.html... I had

```
<script src="js/game.js"></script>
```

And it should be like this

```
<script src="/js/game.js"></script>
```